# codeigniter: pagination links shows and working but not correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

hy every one.
I making a project in codeigniter. I download a template and start working.
when i use pagination pagination links shows correctly but when i click on link it move the link on other controller. i don't know how it works please help me 
thanks in advance
here links
[image]
when i click on this then it moves like this not vehicle
[image]
here is my controller code

```
function vehicle()
{
    if($this->isAdmin() == TRUE)
    {
        $this->loadThis();
    }
    else
    {
        $searchText = $this->input->post('searchText');
        $data['searchText'] = $searchText;            
        //$this->load->library('pagination');            
        $count = $this->hotel_other_model->vehicle_count($searchText);
        $returns = $this->paginationCompress ( "vehicle/", $count, 5);            
        $data['vehicleRecords'] = $this->hotel_other_model->vehicle_list($searchText, $returns["page"], $returns["segment"]);
        $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'CodeInsect : Vehicle Listing';            
        $this->loadViews("hotel_other/vehicle", $this->global, $data, NULL);
    }
}
```

links on view like this

```
<div class="box-footer clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
            </div>
```

paginationCompress() function is here

```
function paginationCompress($link, $count, $perPage = 10) {     
    $config ['base_url'] = base_url () . $link;
    $config ['total_rows'] = $count;
    //$config ['uri_segment'] = SEGMENT;
    $config ['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config ['per_page'] = $perPage;
    $config ['num_links'] = 5;
    $config ['full_tag_open'] = '<nav><ul class="pagination">';
    $config ['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></nav>';
    $config ['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config ['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config ['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config ['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config ['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config ['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config ['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config ['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize ( $config );
    $page = $config ['per_page'];       
    $segment = $this->uri->segment (2);
    return array (
            "page" => $page,
            "segment" => $segment
    );
}
```

please help for this 
thanks again in advance
sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you please post your vehicle controller's code? it looks like your vehicle controller is redirecting to userlisting controller

Comment: controller code is there at question. At here is my controller

Comment: not for this one function. your index method of vehicle controller. and also the full code of this function this is not complete function.

Comment: how can i send you complete file here??

Comment: not full file. just the complete function in which you have written this code and an index method.

Comment: question edited please check

Comment: this looks fine . please check your index method that it is not redirecting to userlisting controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168374/discussion-between-nadeem-ijaz-and-darsh-khakhkhar).

Comment: What does $link in your base url represent? A controller/method I hope?

Comment: thanks to all it is all true but here is problem that a java script code that redirect ....

Answer (score 0):

There is search facility in this code, to make search and pagination both work at a time, there is jQuery code at the end of the view file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('ul.pagination li a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();            
            var link = jQuery(this).get(0).href;            
            var value = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            jQuery("#searchList").attr("action", baseURL + "userListing/" + value);
            jQuery("#searchList").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please check about code.

```
jQuery("#searchList").attr("action", baseURL + "userListing/" + value);
```

Instead of `userListing` you need to give your route. Then it will work.